# PHP cURL Authentication Issue

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I worked with HttpFox and have compared the values (url and post data) with the ones my code has generated. They are completely the same, but I always see the message 'Login failed' on the webpage. I have no idea what could be the problem.

Code:

```
require 'domparser_1_5/simple_html_dom.php';

$username = "username";
$password = "password";

function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();
    $result = curl_exec($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($login);
    unset($login);
    return $result;
}

function generate_pass($user, $password, $token) {
    if ($password) {
        $enc_pass = md5($password);
        $pass = $user.':'.$enc_pass.':'.$token;
        return md5($pass);
    }
}

function get_token() {
    $html = file_get_html('https://www.foo.com/');
    $token = "";
    foreach($html->find('input') as $element) {
        if($element->name == "token") {
            $token = $element->value;
        }
    }
    if (!$token) {
        die('No token found');
    }
    return $token;
}

$token = get_token();

echo login("https://www.foo.com/login/start.html", "user=".$username."&password=".$password."&submit=Anmelden&logintype=login&pid=4%2C93%2C1828&pass=".generate_pass($username, $password, $token)."&redirect_url=login%2Fstart.html&tx_felogin_pi1%5Bnoredirect%5D=0&token=".$token."");
```

Comment: Try to use Guzzle lib, it's more user-friendly. https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: Or you can add Postman Plugin (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm), send your request and see if it really works...

Comment: Why do you have code after `return curl_exec($login);`? The function ends when you use `return`.

Comment: @vanadium23 thanks, I will try this. But it's still interesting for me why the code isn't working.

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira this isn't that easy, because the form of the external webpage generates an individuell token each time you are try to log in.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you're right. I fixed it, but the message 'login failed' still appears.

Comment: Maybe you need `urlencode($password)`? What's the difference between the `password` and `pass` parameters?

Comment: Try to set absolutely cookie file path. I am not sure, but some times it will help.

Comment: @Barmar Still the same 'login failed'. `password` is simply the password. `pass` is a combination of the `username`, the `md5(password)` and the `token`. So it's a kind of security stuff. Look at `generate_pass()`

Comment: Maybe it's something about the `https`?

Comment: @Polvonjon I tried it, but still the same message. I also successfully checked if the cookie file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication fails due to the mismatch between `token` and **cookie(s)** passed.

When you load the page to retrieve the **token** with `get_token()` the server is sending you a cookie that you are not saving.

Later when you try to login the server expects to receive same cookie it sent you when you got the `token`. But you're not sending it.

I suggest you to the rewrite `get_token()` using curl and storing cookies in `cookie.txt`. This will let you pass them later when you'll call `login()`

Like this:

```
function get_token() {
    $url = 'https://www.foo.com/';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    unset($curl);

    $html = str_get_html( $result );
    $token = "";
    foreach($html->find('input') as $element) {
        if($element->name == "token") {
            $token = $element->value;
        }
    }
    if (!$token) {
        die('No token found');
    }
    return $token;
}
```

**Important:**

Remove

```
$fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
fclose($fp);
```

From `login()` as that truncates to zero bytes the `cookie.txt` file, and you don't want to delete the cookie just retrieved.

Note that `curl_exec()` creates the speciefied cookie file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, that sounds logical. Can you give me a code snippet how you would do this?

Comment: Basically you merge the `login` function without passing post data and the original `get_token` using `str_get_html` to initialte html parsing. I posted a snippet. Of course I assume the rest of your code (as you get the token from the htm, how you pass login and pass to the website) is correct. **Imprortant** doon't truncate `cookie.txt` into `login()` see answer

Comment: Also... get the token. Store into variable. Then generate the password. Then do the login. This avoids loading the home page twice.